# Using Filter formula to display cells starting with a specific number

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google spreadsheet I have data which updates automatically. I need to see only cells which start with 1. I have used filter but it didn't workout as after each update filter doesn't update so I am getting wrong values (not only those which start with 1). I know that Filter formula can help me but I don't know how to specify "starts with 1" in it. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to capture only cells starting with 1, you will need to use the [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) formula.

(Let's assume you wanted to filter columns A and B, based on whether or not the data in A starts with 1.)

`=FILTER(A:B,REGEXMATCH(A:A,"^1"))`

The "^1" is a regular expression that captures strings that contain 1 as their first characters.

However, this only works on strings of text, so if your data is numerical, you will need to use the [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) function in the `range` argument of your REGEXMATCH to convert the data into text.

`=FILTER(A:B,REGEXMATCH(TEXT(A:A,0),"^1"))`

Comment: Thew however note was needed! I got 0 matches at first, but had to swap my zip code column to text. Example with other filters parameters.
=count(FILTER('Timeline and Demographic Data'!D:D,MONTH('Timeline and Demographic Data'!D:D)=Month(A43),YEAR('Timeline and Demographic Data'!D:D)=YEAR(A43),REGEXMATCH('Timeline and Demographic Data'!J:J,"^2")))